# How can I use the StreamWriteAsText() to write data of the Number type?

Tags: dm-script

My ultimate goal is to write a file of image data and the time it was taken, for multiple times. This could be used to produce time vs intensity plots.

To do this, I am trying to write a 1D image to a file stream repeatedly in time using the `ImageWriteImageDataToStream()` function. I go about this by attaching a Listener object to the camera view I am reading out and this listener executes a function that writes the image to a file stream using `ImageWriteImageDataToStream()` every time the data changes (`messagemap = "data_changed:MyFunctiontoExecute"`) .

My question is, is there a way to also write a time stamp to this same file stream?

All I can find is StreamWriteAsText(), which takes a String data type. Can I convert time which is a Number type to a String type?

Does anyone have a better way to do this?

My solution at the moment is to create a separate file at the same time and record the timing using WriteFile(), so not using a file stream.

```
//MyFunctiontoExecute, where Img is the 1D image at the current time
My_file_stream.StreamSetPos(2,0)
ImageWriteImageDataToStream(Img, My_file_stream, 0)

//Write the time to the same file
Number tmp_time = GetHighResTickCount() - start_time
My_file_stream.StreamSetPos(2,0)

My_file_stream.StreamWriteAsText(0,tmp_time) //does not work

//instead using a different file
WriteFile(My_extrafileID,tmp_time+"/n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your concept of streaming is wrong. When you stream to a file, at the end of the `toStream()` commands, the stream-position *is already at the end*. So you don't set the position.

Your script essentially tells the computer to set the stream *back* to that starting position and then to write the text - overwriting the data.

You only need the 'StreamSetPos()' command when you want to jump over some sections during reading (useful when defining import-scripts for specific file formats, for example. Or to extract only specific sub-sets from a file.).

If all you want to do is *"stream-out some raw-data"*, you do exactly that: Just call the commands after each other:

```
void WriteDataPlusDateToStream( object fStream, image img, string dateStr )
{
    number endian = 0
    number encoding = 0
    img.ImageWriteImageDataToStream(fStream,endian)
    fStream.StreamWriteAsText(encoding,dateStr) 
}
```

Similarly, you just *"stream-in"* by just following the same sequence:

```
void ReadDataPlusDateFromStream( object fStream, image img, string &dateStr )
{
    number endian = 0
    number encoding = 0
    img.ImageReadImageDataFromStream(fStream,endian)
    fStream.StreamReadTextLine(encoding,dateStr)    
}
```

Two things are important here:

- in `ImageReadImageDataFromStream` it is the *size and data-type* of the image `img` which defines how many bytes are read from the stream and how they are interpreted. Therefore `img` must have been pre-created and of fitting size and file-type.
- in `StreamReadTextLine` the stream will continue to read in *as text* until it encounters the *end-of-line* character (`\n`) or the end of the stream. Therefore make sure to *write* this *end-of-line* character when streaming-out. Alternatively, you can make sure that the strings are always of a specific size and then use `StreamReadAsText` with the appropriate length specified.

Using the two methods above, you can use the following test-script as a starting point:

```
void WriteDataPlusDateToStream( object fStream, image img, string dateStr )
{
    number endian = 0
    number encoding = 0
    img.ImageWriteImageDataToStream(fStream,endian)
    fStream.StreamWriteAsText(encoding,dateStr) 
}
void ReadDataPlusDateFromStream( object fStream, image img, string &dateStr )
{
    number endian = 0
    number encoding = 0
    img.ImageReadImageDataFromStream(fStream,endian)
    fStream.StreamReadTextLine(encoding,dateStr)    
}


void writeTest(string path)
{
    Result("\n Writing to :" + path )
    image testImg := RealImage("Test",4,100)
    string dateStr;
    number loop = 5;

    number doAutoClose = 1
    object fStream = NewStreamFromFileReference( CreateFileForWriting(path), doAutoClose )
    for( number i=0; i<loop; i++ )
    {
        testImg = icol * random()
        dateStr = GetDate(1)+"@"+GetTime(1)+"|"+Format(GetHighResTickCount(),"%.f") + "\n"
        fStream.WriteDataPlusDateToStream(testImg,dateStr)
        sleep(0.33)
    }
}

void readTest(string path)
{
    Result("\n Reading form :" + path )
    image testImg := RealImage("Test",4,100)
    string dateStr;
    number doAutoClose = 1
    object fStream = NewStreamFromFileReference( OpenFileForReading(path), doAutoClose )
    while ( fStream.StreamGetPos() < fStream.StreamGetSize() )
    {
        fStream.ReadDataPlusDateFromStream(testImg,dateStr)
        result("\n time:"+dateStr)
        testImg.ImageClone().ShowImage()
    }
}

string path = "C:/test.dat"
ClearResults()
writeTest(path)
readTest(path)
```

Note, that when streaming "binary data" like this, it is *you* who defines the file-format. You must make sure that the writing and reading code matches up.